# Understanding exchangeArray function in Table Gateway pattern in ZF2

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I am new in ZF2 and i created one module in my application where i have used Table Gateway pattern, I observed that for table gateway exchangeArray() function is being used.

Can Anyone briefed about how exchangeArray() function works internally.

Thanks In Advance !!

Answer (score 2):

The `exchangeArray`method is a function that you need to implement on your business object that populates the business object with a given array. The internal logic of this method is entirely up to you.
Here is a simple example from the documentation: http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/user-guide/database-and-models.html

Comment: can we skip this method and continue with what all data we have?

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do